# SQL обновление нескольких записей одним запросом

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица с колонкой active, в один момент времени может быть активна только одна запись. Необходимо делать UPDATE записи и ставить значение active в true, и одновременно ставить в false значение active в старой записи. Подскажите как это сделать одним запросом.

**Пример**

Исходная таблица

`id   name  active
 1     a     true
 2     b     false
 3     c     false`

После

`id   name  active
 1     a     false
 2     b     true
 3     c     false`

Comment: Уточню, например у записи с id 1 статус true, мне нужно активировать запись 2 (например, там может быть любая другая), при активации записи с id 2, у id 1 одновременно должен установиться active в false

Comment: Хм, ваш пример похож на правду, но что то он у меня не срабатывает

Comment: На мой взгляд, сама идея порочна. Нелепо менять множество, если значимо одно значение. Храните ключ активной записи в стороне.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update меняющий у одной записи active на true и у всех других записей, которые сейчас active на false (гарантирует, что в таблице только одна запись может быть true):

```
with Q as (
 select * from testBool where active=true or id=3
)
update testBool T set active=not T.active from Q
 where exists(select 1 from Q where active=false)
   and T.id=Q.id
```

Answer (score 3):

Есть вот такой **безумный** вариант:

```sql
UPDATE actives
   SET active = (id = 1);
--              ^^^^^^^^ это ж boolean!
```

Условие будет соблюдено, если на поле выборки есть констрейнт `UNIQUE`, чтобы `true` из равенства могло выпасть лишь для одной строки таблицы. Однако, *если такого ключа в таблице нет совсем*, **всё сбросится на `false`**. Можно добавить условие на `id`, содержащее `SELECT` из той же таблицы, чтобы таких ситуаций избежать.

Безумным я его считаю потому, что база вряд ли догадается узнать, сколько записей в результате запроса **реально изменится**, а мы знаем, что таких всегда *не более двух*. База же будет обходить все строки.

<sub>Но надо измерять производительность и выяснять, возможно, эта проблема существует только в моей голове. Но даже если нет, более быстрое решение целостности ради может просто не существовать. **Я не знаю.**</sub>

<sub>[Евгений Борисов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177016/%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2) в комментариях к вопросу правильно отмечает, что гораздо эффективнее хранить в другом месте первичный ключ активной записи. Единственное место можно атомарно менять с куда меньшими блокировками.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

C помощью триггеров:

```
Crteate trigger trig
Before inser or update or delete on TABLE 
For Each ROW
Execute Prosedure reset_all_to_false()
```

---

Функция:

```
Create Function reset_all_to_false()
returns void
Begin 
update table set active = false where active = true;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

возможно подойдет такой вариант ?

с начало устанавливаем false 

`update table set active = false where active = true`

а затем устанавливаем нужную строчку

`update table set active = true where условие`

2 вариант

`update t set active = case  when *условие true*  then true else false  end`

но этот вариант плох что по всей таблице  пройдет можно дописать еще условия для ограничения

Comment: Подошел бы, но надо одним запросом

Comment: @sscream можно в транзакцию завернуть. Хотя одним запросом наверняка тоже можно.

Comment: транзакция как вариант, но я тоже думаю, что все таки можно одним запросом